# JBoss eap-6 boundPort and boundAddress MBean

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x

We are trying to get the boundAddress and boundPort for JBoss server at the time of the Jvm startup. We have a jvm agent which starts with JBoss server and while trying to get the  boundPort and boundAddress through MBean we are getting exception as,

^[[0m^[[31m16:03:34,066 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) **javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: jboss.as.expr:socket-binding-group=full-sockets,socket-binding=http**

^[[0m^[[31m16:03:34,067 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54)        at org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerImpl.findDelegate(PluggableMBeanServerImpl.java:94)

^[[0m^[[31m16:03:34,067 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54)        at org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerImpl.getAttribute(PluggableMBeanServerImpl.java:171)
....
....

Same piece of code works if we deploy our agent after the server has initialized. I tried loop around the try-catch block where the exception is coming, assuming MBean server might be waiting for initialization but that also did not work.

I would like to know if there is any better way to get these values at the time of startup.

Thanks,
Rupesh